# How to link features files with the step definitions using Cypress io

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am currently using cucumber with cypress io for testing, however, unlike when using selenium with cucumber/Gherkin that allows you to trace each scenario step to the corresponding step definition step by pressing down the control key and clicking against the scenario step, this is not happening with cypress io. The test also failed when using the below syntax;

```
given(/^I entered a valid client id as "([^"]*)"$/, (client_id) => {
    cy.get('#bpId')
        .clear()
        .type(client_id);
});
```

Could someone help me with the way to solve these problems? I am new to cypress.

Answer (score 2):

I have ran into a similar problem, while setting up the project. 
I have created a file named, `.cypress-cucumber-preprocesorrc` and added this line in there

```
{
    "step_definitions": "cypress/integration/**/step_definitions/"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to integrate cucumber and cypress is the [cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/README.md). Under the hood, this module uses [cosmiconfig](https://github.com/davidtheclark/cosmiconfig), which allows you to specify json or yaml configuration.

The configuration file naming conventions are explained in the [cosmiconfig README](https://github.com/davidtheclark/cosmiconfig/blob/master/README.md):

> By default, Cosmiconfig will start where you tell it to start and search up the directory tree for the following:
>
> - a package.json property
> - a JSON or YAML, extensionless "rc file"
> - an "rc file" with the extensions .json, .yaml, .yml, or .js.
> - a .config.js CommonJS module
>
> For example, if your module's name is "myapp", cosmiconfig will search up the directory tree for configuration in the following places:
>
> - a myapp property in package.json
> - a .myapprc file in JSON or YAML format
> - a .myapprc.json file
> - a .myapprc.yaml, .myapprc.yml, or .myapprc.js file
> - a myapp.config.js file exporting a JS object

This is why the [configuration file in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53936605/124237) works.